# 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 5140 pos 12: '_history.isNotEmpty': is not true

Tags: flutter

**This error comes when I use Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil, This is not repeatable and occurs randomly.**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Error occurs because there no screen in navigator stack when you try to pop. Your _history is becomes empty. So, it returns the assertion false for _history.isNotEmpty.

When you try to use Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil. You need to check whether there is any screen left after performing this because after this it will perform the push function.

How Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil works ?

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushAndRemoveUntil.html